# npm start gives an error

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

I have installed different packages through npm to run a simple hello world application in React (I am new to it). After their installation, the `package.json` has this format.

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "test",
  "main": "index.js"
},
  "repository": {
  "type": "git",
  "url": "https://github.com/theo82"
},
  "keywords": [
  "test"
],
 "author": "Theo Tziomakas",
 "license": "ISC",
 "dependencies": {
 "react": "^15.4.2",
 "react-dom": "^15.4.2",
 "webpack": "^2.2.1"
  }
}
```

After running the **npm start** in cmd(windows 8.1),I get this error.

```
 npm ERR! Unexpected token ',' at 6:4
 npm ERR!   },
 npm ERR!    ^
```

In various answers people solved this problem by using a clean cache as

```
npm cache clean
```

However,this does not work for me:(. Any ideas why is this happening?

Thanks,

Theo.

Comment: it's syntax error

Answer (score 0):

There are syntax errors in your file. Also you should specify what your `start` script should do. For example, when you run `npm start` node should execute the `index.js` file

```js
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "test",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js" 
  },
  "keywords": [
    "test"
  ],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reading my question. However,your answer doesn't work.

Comment: Are you sure you have index.js file in your root directory ? `start` script is not some default script of npm. `start` script could be anything you want it to be. In my example it executes index.js file inside root directory

Answer (score 0):

The syntax of your package.json have some problem, there is a extra `}` after the line of the key `main`

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "test",
  "main": "index.js",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/theo82"
   },
  "keywords": [
    "test"
  ],
 "author": "Theo Tziomakas",
 "license": "ISC",
 "dependencies": {
   "react": "^15.4.2",
   "react-dom": "^15.4.2",
   "webpack": "^2.2.1"
  }
}
```